# Show statements about "sums" and "square roots" of ideals

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Show:

(1) $I+J:=\{i+j|i \in I,j \in J\}=\langle I \cup J \rangle_R$

(2) $\sqrt{I} := \{x \in R | x^n \in I, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an ideal of $R$ and $I \subset \sqrt{I}$. Find an example so that $I \subsetneq \sqrt{I}$.

For (1) I have written out the definition of an ideal generated by a set:

$\langle I \cup J \rangle_R=\{\sum_{l=1}^n r_l a_l | n \in \mathbb{N}_0, a_1,...,a_n \in I \cup J, r_1,...,r_n \in R\}$. Clearly the $a_i$ are elements of $I$ and $J$. If I could somehow rewrite the sum I might end up with the definition of $I+J$ in a) but I don't see how to do this.

As for b) I also need some assistance.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For (1) use the fact that $a_m,a_k\in I$ (or both in $J$)  you can deuce that $r_m a_m +r_k a_k\in I$ (or to $J$). This also works for any number, so you can deduce that your sum belongs to $I+J$. The inclusion $I+J\subseteq \langle I\cup J\rangle _R$ is pretty trivial.

For (2) the inclusion is also easy. If $x\in I$ then $n=1$ we will have $x^n \in I$, and actually, any $n$ will work.

To find an example for $I\subsetneq \sqrt{I}$ try to think about ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$, they are of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$, for what n we can $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m|x^n$ but $n$ doesn't divide $x$? (you can think about $m=2$).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to complete (1) but for (2) I'm struggling to show that it is an ideal. For that I need to show that $\sqrt{I}$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Sure! Multiplication is easier because if  $x^n\in I$ then $(rx)^n=r^n x^n\in I$ as well. For addition there is a nice trick, if $x^n\in I, y^m\in I$ what can you say about $(x+y)^{n+m}$? (n+m can be replaced by any $k\geq n,m$).

Comment: I'm thinking about writing $(x+y)^{n+m)$ out using the binomial theorem but then I don't know where to go with the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Every term is of the form $\binom{n+m}{k} x^k y^{n+m-k}$ and so it must be that $k\leq n$ or $n+m-k\geq m$, in each case you can deuce that the term is in $\sqrt{I}$.